# Проверка строки на палиндром

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть файлик palindromes.txt с исходными данными, нужно проверить является ли строки в нем палиндромами

```
def remove_signs(s):
    s = s.lower()
    signs = "?!. \'\"`,:;-_/()[]~"
    s_without_signs = ""
    for letter in s:
        if letter not in signs:
            s_without_signs += letter
    return s_without_signs


with open('palindromes.txt', 'r')as f:
    for line in f:
        text = remove_signs(line)
        if text == text[::-1]:
            print('Y', ' ')
        else:
            print('N', ' ')
```

Все время выдает N

Comment: исходный файл то приложите

Comment: Функция `remove_signs` здесь не нужно. В библиотеке есть `string.punctuation` и `strip` как их исползовать? см мой ответ.

Comment: Здесь бы больше подошёл `str.replace`, но только заменяющий сразу много символов. `str.strip` делает именно это, но только по краям строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё практически правильно. Дело в том, что вместе с нужными строками, из файла вы читаете и символ конца строки `\n`. Это можно заметить, если преобразовать в list считанную строку. Всё, что Вам нужно - убрать и этот символ из строки, добавив его в `signs`.

```
signs = "?!. \'\"`,:;-_/()[]~\n"
```

Comment: Да все заработало, спасибо.

Comment: [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation)  дает список символ. таким оброзом можно просто испозовать `strip`

Comment: Ок. `signs = string.punctuation + '\n'` Про `strip` написал ниже.

Answer (score 1):

вариант с генератором списков и pythonic-функцией reversed

```
def def_palindrom(phrase):
    phrase_1 = [x.lower() for x in phrase if x.isalpha()]
    phrase_2 = list(reversed(phrase_1))
    if phrase_1 == phrase_2:
        print(phrase, '- ПАЛИНДРОМ')
    else:
        print(phrase, ' - НЕ ПАЛИНДРОМ')
```

Comment: Кстати, а код можно оптимизировать: программе незачем сравнивать вторую половину строки с перевёрнутой первой.
`phrase_1 = [x.lower() for x in phrase[:len(phrase) // 2:] if x.isalpha()]`
`phrase_2 = [x.lower() for x in phrase[:(len(phrase) - 1) // 2: -1] if x.isalpha()]`

Answer (score 1):

нужно использовать [**`string.punctuation`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) и [**`strip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

```
import string

unwanted_char = string.punctuation + '\n'
with open('palindromes.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        stripped_line = line.strip(unwanted_char).lower()
        if stripped_line == stripped_line[::-1]
            print('Y', ' ')
        else:
            print('N', ' ')
```

---

Пример:

```
>>> import string
>>> unwanted_char = string.punctuation + '\n'
>>> unwanted_char
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\n'
>>> line = "Пап[],.{}\@#$\n"
>>> stripped_line = line.strip(unwanted_char).lower()
>>> stripped_line == stripped_line[::-1]
True
```

---

Если символы пунктуации будут где-то в середине лучшее исползовать регулярные выражения.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "&%$#   Пап[],.{}\@#$\n"
>>> re.sub(r'\W+', '', line)
'Пап'
>>> s = re.sub(r'\W+', '', line).lower()
>>> s == s[::-1]
True
```

Comment: Это вряд ли улучшит ситуацию. `strip` убирает символы лишь из начала и конца строки, причём `\n` там всё равно останется. Приведённый код для файла не сработает. Особенно, если символы пунктуации будут где-то в середине.

Comment: @diversenok Да правда но если если символы пунктуации в середине я бы использолвал  регулярные выражения.